# i can not wrap child(Image, TextInput) with parent View. How can I fix this?

Tags: react-native, styles, stylesheet

I'm making an app related to map, and using the react-native-maps package. So, I've tried to wrap the child component such as Image, ImageBackground, TextInput inside View component, but the result of rendering is sometimes right, and sometimes wrong.
The child components are not always correct to render. Sometimes the child components are not set own's location.

react native

```
      <View style={styles.searchBar}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('./assets/search.png')}
          style={styles.searchImage}></ImageBackground>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="food, store, ingredient"
          style={styles.searchText}></TextInput>
      </View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({ searchBar: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: "white",
flexDirection: 'row',
alignItems: 'center',
alignContent: 'center',
justifyContent: 'flex-start',
paddingHorizontal: 5,
marginHorizontal: 10,
borderRadius: 8, 
shadowColor: "#000", 
shadowRadius: 2,
shadowOpacity: 0.2, 
shadowOffset: { x: 0.5, y: -0.5 }, }, searchImage: {
flex: 1,
width: 32, 
height: 32, 
marginLeft: 5, }, searchText: {
flex: 9,
fontSize: 17,
marginHorizontal: 1, },  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The child does not need a flex value. You are already arranging using the 'roll' value, and have set the image size small.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
searchBar: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: "white",
flexDirection: 'row',
alignItems: 'center',
paddingHorizontal: 10,
borderRadius: 8, 
shadowColor: "#000", 
shadowRadius: 2,
shadowOpacity: 0.2, 
shadowOffset: { x: 0.5, y: -0.5 }, 
}, 

searchImage: {
width: 32, 
height: 32, 
marginLeft: 5, },

 searchText: {
fontSize: 17,
marginHorizontal: 1, },  });
```